# Clauses with no subject

Tags: clauses, subjects

I've been reading that English does not permit clauses without a subject (except imperative sentences and infinitive verbs, right?). So I don't understand phenomena such as:

- We've updated our Privacy Policy which ***will go into effect in September***.

What am I missing??

Comment: **Which** is a pronoun referring to the updated Privacy Policy. It is the subject of the bolded part of your sentence.

Comment: Right. _Which will go into effect in September_ is a relative clause modifying _policy_, and the relative pronoun _which_ is the subject of that relative clause. But lots of subject and other words do get lost, like _Ever been to Barcelona?_

Comment: Do search for "*relative clause*" to learn more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a clause generally consists of a subject and a predicate. Sometimes the subject can be omitted. E.g.:

> Alice taught English for five years.
> I couldn't hear you. What did Alice do?
> **Taught English for five years.**

Sometimes the predicate can be omitted. E.g.:

> Who taught English for five years?
> **Alice.**

However, in your example neither is omitted. You've highlighted the predicate. Its subject is the pronoun "which" (as Weather Vane noted in a comment above). In this case, "which" is a relative pronoun and refers to "our privacy policy".

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but the antecedent of "which" is just "privacy policy". Determiners like "our" are not part of an antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ I normally consider a determiner to be part of a nominal phrase.

Comment: Not to worry. Grammarians consider the nominal to be an NP less the determiner (if present), e.g in the NP "A [young boy]" the bracketed bit is the nominal. Sometimes called n1 in parsing diagrams.

Comment: @BillJ And, as I'm sure you know, other grammarians consider NPs to include determiners. Both ways are acceptable.

Comment: Yes, NPs do of course include determiners. But a nominal is not an NP: it's the bit intermediate between the NP and the head noun, So the example "A young boy" is indeed an NP in which "young boy" is the nominal. Is that clearer?

Comment: @BillJ I define terms differently than you do, an issue that we've encountered several times before. No problem, different definitions are common in grammar.

Answer (score 0):

We've updated our Privacy Policy. **It** will go into effect in September.

'We've updated our Privacy Policy **which** will go into effect in September.'

'Which' joins the two clauses together. 'Which' is the subject of the second clause. We use 'which' in the same way as 'it'. 'Which' is a relative pronoun. It can also be an object of a clause.